# TFS Team Explorer "BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently."

Tags: tfs

Has anyone come across this error message?  I am no longer able to checkin code to TFS.  I tried restarting my computer but it didn't help.

[image](http://i45.tinypic.com/2gumybk.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a pending conflict. You need to resolve those before you can continue.

In vS2012, to to the Team Explorer window and select Actions -> Resolve Conflicts and solve your conflict.